# Is it possible to call a property through another model?

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm studying django and drf and I want to pass some information trough serializer.

I have two models:

```py
class ModelA():
    ...
```

and

```py
class ModelB():
    ...
    @property
    def anything(self)
        return ...
```

Is it possible for ModelA to call the ModelB property? How could I do this?

Comment: if you have `someb`, then you can `someb.anything` from anywhere. But perhaps this is not what you are looking for?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thank you.  I need, maybe, create another property in ModelA with "anything" return. My goal is to send this return in a ModelA serializer